# Is it possible to summon creatures without the sword of summoning?

Tags: candy-box

I have the 'sword of flames', and don't have the option to summon anything.

Is there anyway I can summon creatures without the 'sword of summoning'. I'm currently stuck on a level, and the suggestion is to summon an Imp to help me.

Otherwise, is there something equivalent I can do without the sword of summoning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a scroll that you can use to summon imps. It is the Imp Invocation Scroll. I forget how you get them early on though. I know you can eventually buy them from the merchant and sometimes you find them. [More info can be found here](http://www.candyboxwiki.com/wiki/Scrolls#Imp_Invocation_Scroll).

Comment: Thanks, I just hit up the merchant for scrolls until I got an Imp invocation scroll.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a cloning potion you can craft with the cauldron.